# Getting more information about memory from Perfmon

Tags: windows-7, performance

It is possible to set up counters in windows perform to get information about memory. Some useful counters include:

```
Pages/sec
Available Bytes
```

However, this give me information for my entire system.  What I'd like would be able to track the amount of memory a particular process (e.g. a JVM) was using.  Any tips how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Physical memory? Virtual memory? What's your outer problem? What do you plan to do with the information? (For example, physical memory tells you more about performance on *this* machine. But virtual memory tells you more about resource consumption of the application independent of the local system's specifications.)

Comment: I want to monitor memeory usage of a JVM over a long period of time.  I do not expect its virtual memory to be greater than physical memory. The Pages/sec tells me the amount of swapping. I expect this to be very low. It would nice to get both physical and virtual memory but more important to get either for my JVM rather than the entire OS which is what windows does by default.

Comment: Why on earth would you NOT expect virtual memory to be greater than physical memory? That's part of the whole point of virtual memory.

Answer (score 1):

Task Manager displays a half-dozen or so Memory counters on a per-process basis. Also Page Faults, and more.

Comment: Yes but can I direct these to log files? Or set alerts from them?  You know, that fact that task manager does me make me believe perfmon must be able to.

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at RamMap,](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229) not sure if it has all the features you need. I don't think it logs anything though.

.